# How to print more lines of a tbl_graph object

Tags: r

I have the following tidy graph

```
library(tidygraph)
library(tibble)
mynodes <- tibble(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
myedges <- tibble(from = c(1,1,1,5,2,2,4,8,8,8),
                  to = c(1,2,3,4,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                  power = c(10,10,10,3,3,3,2,2,2,2))
graph = tbl_graph(nodes = mynodes, edges = myedges)
```

the output is the following

```
graph
# A tbl_graph: 10 nodes and 10 edges
#
# A directed multigraph with 5 components
#
# A tibble: 10 × 1
     id
  <dbl>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     6
# ℹ 4 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
#
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   from    to power
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     1    10
2     1     2    10
3     1     3    10
# ℹ 7 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

How I can print more lines?
I have read various solutions for tidy df but none for "tbl_graph" "igraph" object.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `lapply` with `print` and the `nrow` to show all rows like this:

```r
library(tidygraph)
library(tibble)
mynodes <- tibble(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
myedges <- tibble(from = c(1,1,1,5,2,2,4,8,8,8),
                  to = c(1,2,3,4,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                  power = c(10,10,10,3,3,3,2,2,2,2))
graph = tbl_graph(nodes = mynodes, edges = myedges)
lapply(graph, \(x) x %>% print(n = nrow(.)))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 1
#>       id
#>    <dbl>
#>  1     1
#>  2     2
#>  3     3
#>  4     4
#>  5     5
#>  6     6
#>  7     7
#>  8     8
#>  9     9
#> 10    10
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>     from    to power
#>    <int> <int> <dbl>
#>  1     1     1    10
#>  2     1     2    10
#>  3     1     3    10
#>  4     5     4     3
#>  5     2     3     3
#>  6     2     4     3
#>  7     4     1     2
#>  8     8     2     2
#>  9     8     3     2
#> 10     8     4     2
#> $nodes
#> # A tibble: 10 × 1
#>       id
#>    <dbl>
#>  1     1
#>  2     2
#>  3     3
#>  4     4
#>  5     5
#>  6     6
#>  7     7
#>  8     8
#>  9     9
#> 10    10
#> 
#> $edges
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>     from    to power
#>    <int> <int> <dbl>
#>  1     1     1    10
#>  2     1     2    10
#>  3     1     3    10
#>  4     5     4     3
#>  5     2     3     3
#>  6     2     4     3
#>  7     4     1     2
#>  8     8     2     2
#>  9     8     3     2
#> 10     8     4     2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>